# Create a duplication of object in an array

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am running sample application in react-native. I have a sample array with list of objects i.e., **[a,b,c,d,e]**. I am creating a duplication of  **object a** in an array and it's creates a duplicate of **object a** and i am creating another object duplication in an array but it is replaced with **object a** duplication. How to solve this issue...Please help me.
Here is my code:

```
export default class AllCategories_list extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 })
    }
  }
duplicate(index) {
    var duplication = []
    var duplicationObj = Object.assign({}, index) //Object.create(duplicateArray)

    duplication.push(duplicationObj)
    alert(JSON.stringify(duplication))
    var finalArray = array.concat(duplication)
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(finalArray)
    })
  }
rowData(list) {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(list))
    return (
      <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.duplicate.bind(this, list)}>

          <Text style={styles.item}>{list}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ListView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          // horizontal={true}
          renderRow={this.rowData.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign, Object.assign does not do deep cloning, "For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because Object.assign() copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value."

Provided your objects are serializable, then you can do like this

```
    duplicate(index) {
      var finalArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(index));
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(finalArray)
      })
    }
```

Comment: Hi, @Karthikeyan thanks for your reply......................
`var finalArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(index));`
this is also replaced the object

Comment: Which object did it replace? Please provide more details. finalArray is a new array of objects that was parsed from a string. So if you make any modifications in finalArray that will not change the index.

Comment: Hi, @Karthikeyan.....I find solution for this.............Declare the **var duplication = []** into global array.....

Answer (score -1):

I find solution for this.............

Declare the **var duplication = []** into global array..... It does not replaces the objects in an array......